# Queries with empty values from parse.com

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parse-platform, synchronization

Somehow I couldn't find the answer to this.

I am running a query to parse.com and want to download all of the rows that contain an empty value in one of my columns.

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Constants.myTestTable);
    query.whereEqualTo("MyColumn", "");
```

When I upload a csv to parse where MyColumn does not have any value the column cells on parse show "(undefined)" and I cannot retrieve the data. However, when I delete all content in the cell I am able to retrieve it. I want to be able to retrieve the data if the cell has the default "(undefined)" value from parse. I tried...

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Constants.myTestTable);
        query.whereEqualTo("MyColumn", null);
```

But that did not work either. I'm sure there is an easy solution to this, I just can't get the dang thing to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want are `whereExists` and `whereDoesNotExist`.

```
query.whereDoesNotExist("MyColumn");
```