# NullPointerException for Parse Query

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-spinner

I'm basically asking for the current user's "gender" then setting the selection of the spinner to that value. That works all fine. The problem is that I introduced the new gender field only recently so all older users don't have a value specified in that row and that causes a NullPointer.

How can I properly address this? My null check doesn't seem to work. What could it be?

**(Edit) Solution:** The final answer looks like this:

```
// Initiate ParseQuery
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            if (currentUser.getString("gender") == null) {
                return;
            }
        }

        String compareValue;
        compareValue = currentUser.getString("gender");
        if (!(compareValue == null)) {
            int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(compareValue);
            spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
        } else {
            spinner.setSelection(0);
        }
```

Comment: Please post your whole `EditProfileActivity` class

Comment: Have you check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33428489/5059946) this answer...where you have to put ||(or condition) instead of && (and condition).

Comment: Weird. When I changed the value in the row on Parse to blank from (undefined) it worked. I suppose it's looking for an empty string. How could I change to check for (undefined)?

Comment: @shreyashmashru I have but that didn't solve the problem. It looks like I have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463734/queries-with-empty-values-from-parse-com. I have to check for "undefined" values as opposed to empty strings because that is what the majority of my Parse entries are after adding the new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user is authenticated, you can get values like below. Don't do toString() your parseObject.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

if (currentUser != null) {
    Log.e("currentUser" , ""+currentUser);
    String username = user.getString("username");
    String gender = user.getString("gender");
} else {
    // show the signup or login screen
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Also you can assign default gender (for old users, as it is mandatory field now) to avoid NullPointer Exception

Comment: It definitely cleans up the code, but doesn't quite solve the problem. Thanks though! This issue is "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference"

Comment: See my edit. Try to log currentuser and what you are getting check.

Comment: Glad to help you buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
Check 

if ( currentUser == null && currentUser.get("gender") == null)
{
     return;
}

instead of this...

if(currentUser == null) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. It always points back to this line: final String defaultGenderSelection = currentUser.get("gender").toString();

Comment: Is that crash on condition or on "final String defaultGenderSelection = currentUser.get("gender").toString();" this line?

Comment: The crash is on the line.final String defaultGenderSelection = currentUser.get("gender").toString();

Comment: There is a minor error. You should have || (or) instead of && (and). Hop you get it.

Comment: It means it does't go inside condition block. Please debug the code and trace currentUser and currentUser.get("gender") value.